# JQuery select only items that are inside `this`?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, addclass

I'm trying to affect only elements inside the submitted form (`this`). This is what I'm trying right now:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    $(this + '[name="field"]').addClass('fill-field');
    });
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).filter('[name="birthday[day]"]').addClass('fill-field');
$(this).is('[name="birthday[day]"]').addClass('fill-field');
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I just changed it. Is it more clear? I'm not sure if it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    $(this).find('[name="field"]').addClass('fill-field') ;

    // $(this).find('[name="birthday[day]"]').addClass('fill-field');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$( '[name="field"]',this).addClass('fill-field');